# Automatically connect to a hidden wireless network?

Tags: network-manager

Maybe I'm just missing something, but in Precise and Quantal I haven't been able to figure out how to automatically connect to a hidden wireless network.  How can I enable this from within the network manager?  I **don't** want to just add a custom startup script as this is a laptop and I don't startup/shutdown very often (suspend and hibernate are better alternatives during the day).

Comment: This is not the answer to your question. However, Some versions ago I lost the ability to connect to hidden WiFi network and I have un-hidden my network since. It is not a big loss. See: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28653/debunking-myths-is-hiding-your-wireless-ssid-really-more-secure/

Comment: Yeah... I wish I could, but unfortunately it's not my wireless connection ;( (thanks for the suggestion though; it's important to get the word out about un-hiding SSIDs)

Comment: This seems utterly broken in NetworkManager. I think it's [LP Bug #1035583](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1035583).

Comment: Wow, that's really disappointing.  Thanks (glad to know I'm not alone, though)!

Comment: Are you saying that you want NetworkManager unconditionally to try to connect to Wi-Fi network foo on startup?

Comment: No.  I want it to try to connect to the hidden wireless as promised by the checkbox in Network Manager - whenever wireless is enabled and there is no other connection active.

Comment: I **do not** want anything **just** on startup, as explained in my question.

Comment: log into https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1035583 and mark as it affects you. More people mark the bug, the chances of getting it fixed will be higher. Also, since this is a bug, I will mark the question as off topic.

Comment: It's not that bug.  I never get a dialogue.